# Oque é "-1.#IND" em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tenho uma variável que está recebendo esse valor, que não é uma STRING, então oque é isso? E tem alguma forma de detectar se a variável é igual a isso através de um IF?

Comment: Dê um contexto de onde i sto está ocorrendo, coloque o código.

Comment: Isso é um infinito negativo e você pode tentar condicionar utilizando a função double.IsNaN() para verificar se é um número ou não (sugestão).

Comment: Autocompletou errado, o correto é **negativo indefinido**.

Comment: O Double.IsNaN() funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

### Negativo Indefinido "-1.#IND"

O `NaN Indefinido`, que é um tipo especial de `NaN` *silencioso* é gerado sob condições específicas. Se você executar uma **operação aritmética inválida** como adicionar **infinito positivo** e **infinito negativo**, ou tomar a raiz quadrada de um número negativo, então o [padrão IEEE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante) requer que o resultado seja um `NaN` *silencioso*, mas não parece especificar exatamente o que `NaN` *silencioso* . Diferentes fabricantes de processadores de `ponto flutuante` escolheram caminhos diferentes. 
O termo indefinido `NaN` refere-se a este `NaN` *silencioso* especial, qualquer que seja o processador acaba por escolhê-lo para ser.

Alguns processadores de ponto flutuante geram um `NaN` *silencioso* com os bits de sinal claros, mas o bit de sinal definido. Ajustar o bit de sinal torna o resultado negativo, então nesses processadores, você verá o `indefinido NaN` renderizado como um negativo indefinido NaN. (O x86 é um desses processadores.)

Outros processadores de `ponto flutuante` geram um `NaN` *silencioso* com os bits de sinal e o bit de sinal tudo limpo. Limpar o bit de sinal torna o resultado positivo, então nesses processadores, você verá o indefinido NaN renderizado como um indefinido positivo NaN.

Na prática, a diferença não é importante, porque de qualquer maneira, você terá um `NaN indefinido`.

Texto traduzido de https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130221-00/?p=5183

**Como validar - exemplo:**

```
double a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;
double resultado = (a - b) / c;
if (double.IsNaN(resultado)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Não é um número!");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Número válido!");
}
```